# ListView disabled background color

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

Hi I draw my items in a ListView by myself (`OwnerDraw = true`). I don't use `DrawDefault = true` as I want to have consistent appearance in all styles (Windows Classic, Aero, etc). Now I have the problem that I have to draw the background even if the ListView is disabled. And I can't find the right color for that. The disabled background color of the item should fit the background color of the ListView dependent of the user selected style in Windows. Any ideas how to get this color? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SystemColors.Window`

Comment: Unfortunately this is the color of the enabled `ListView`. I need the color of the **disabled** `ListView` background.

Comment: I believe that there is no system color for this at all but that the normal color is modified in a specific way to appear grayed. I found something similar with disabled images in `ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled`. But I don't know if I'm right about control backgrounds and if so, how to adapt this method to backgrounds.

Comment: You are right it is not really `SystemColors.Window` even though it says so! (Testing it with `            this.Text = LV.BackColor.ToKnownColor().ToString() + "  -  " + LV.Items[3].BackColor.ToKnownColor().ToString();
`). So I guess you are right, it seems to use maybe a version of one of the Incative.* colors. It is not just the desaturated normal color though - using a dark one shows that the disabled color is not darker or changed in any way..

Comment: It is Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control) in Winforms.  Text should be rendered with KnownColor.GrayText.  Do tag your questions properly please.

Comment: Hello Hans. Thank you now it fits. How should I tag the question next time?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for it, too. It is static member of ListView class: `ListView.DefaultBackColor`.